# Is it possible to update the source tab in Google Sheets with changes made to a Query(Filter()) formula output in Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation, google-sheets-formula

I had some contact list in the "Schedule" sheet and I have a dropdown in cell G6 of "CRR-NBD FMS" sheet, the output is whichever month mathces in cell G6 with the column A of "Schedule" sheet will render those particular rows in "Crr-Nbd FMS". It is acheivable through Query(Filter()) formula, but the iutput of that is not editable.

I did the automation of query(filter()) formula, Now I want the checkboxes from column H9:AI to be editable, so that when someone ckeck or uncheck those boxes, the changes to be kept in the output tab(CRR-NBD FMS) also the changes should be updated in the source tab "Schedule"

```
function updateSchedule() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var crrnbdSheet = ss.getSheetByName("CRR-NBD FMS");
  var scheduleSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Schedule");

  var editedRange = crrnbdSheet.getRange("H9:AI");
  var editedValues = editedRange.getValues();
  var scheduleRange = scheduleSheet.getRange("H9:AI");

  scheduleRange.setValues(editedValues);
}

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
    .addItem('Update Schedule', 'updateSchedule')
    .addToUi();
}

function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var crrnbdSheet = ss.getSheetByName("CRR-NBD FMS");
  var scheduleSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Schedule");

  var editedRange = crrnbdSheet.getRange("H9:AI");
  var editedValues = editedRange.getValues();
  var scheduleRange = scheduleSheet.getRange("H9:AI");

  scheduleRange.setValues(editedValues);
}
```

Comment: Your onEdit function will be called for every user edit of every cell in your spread sheet.  I would recommend rethinking it.

Comment: Using ranges like `sh.getRange("H9:AI")` should be avoid try this instead `sh.getRange("h9:AI" + sh.getLastRow());` Not specifying the last row in Google Apps Script often results in null added to the end of the array from but sh.getLastRow() to sh.getMaxRows();